# Stream Video from Android to Internet

Tags: video, streaming, android

I have an old Android phone (Droid 1) that I no longer use but, if possible, I'd like to set it up so that it streams a video feed to the internet.  Something I can view in a browser.  Obviously, it would need to work in conjunction with some app on the phone.

I've been searching for possible solutions but, haven't come across anything.  Most articles/apps discuss streaming video TO the phone, rather than FROM it.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried asking this on the Android Enthusiasts site?

Comment: @Tog I have not.  I did a search there and didn't find anything.  Although, after looking through some posts, it seems they frown on posts like this (app suggestions).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Qik application/service.
They support live video streaming from Droid1.
Also http://www.justin.tv/p/android and http://www.ustream.tv/everywhere/android

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't had luck with any of these.  Qik allows me to take private video but, it freezes when I try to broadcast private video.  Both Justin.tv and Ustream.tv don't allow private channels.

Comment: Hmm, you did not specify that private streaming was one of the requirements..Maybe explain a bit better what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Something along the lines of a security camera.  Keeping an eye on my kids/pets, from the office.